# Page navigation from a pivot control

Tags: uwp, c++-cli, windows-10-universal

My application is pivot based. I have a pivot control which contains few pivot items. And from one of the pivot item (Settings) i want to navigate to another page(Settings edit page).

This is how i am navigating to setting page.

```
void MainPage::OnChangeSettingsClicked(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    ViewModelSettings->ChangeSettings();
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(SettingsPage::typeid));
}
```

This takes me to full screen settings page nicely.

I am coming back to the MainPage as below :

```
void SettingsPage::OnCancelSettingsButtonClicked(Object^ sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(MainPage::typeid));
}
```

This also brings me back to mainpage nicely.

But when i try to switch pivot or do anything inside pivot i am getting below exception :

```
Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::DisconnectedException
```

Why am i trapped with disconnected exception afterward. Am i missing something?

Comment: can you check if calling `this->Frame->GoBack()` from the settings page fixes it or not?

Comment: @Pratyay i checked it already. Did not work

Comment: When I used the code to operate like you, it worked well. Can you show the complete code for us to reproduce? In addition, this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/platform-disconnectedexception-class?view=vs-2019) describes the scenario in which the exception occurs, you can check if there is such a problem with the code.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT This is hard to share the complete picture. Only thing that you may need to know is the pivot in main page and the settings page uses same view model for data binding. And the bound properties are changed from secondary thread.

Comment: If the code only about the navigation between mainpage and settingspage, and remove other influencing factors(like data binding, ect.), will the same problem occur?